# Overflow chat_id in Telegram API

Tags: telegram

I want to add user to chat via telegram API.the chat_id type is integer but the chat_id that i have is too long for integer data type and it is long data type( for example chat_id: -1001027811592).

I have recompiled telegram API with long data type but server return error.The error is  INPUT_CONSTRUCTOR_INVALID.

I think that I have to change API layer (now is Layer#12).
If problem is for api layer, where can i find that API layer library ?
What do i have to do for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Note that all int32, int64, long etc on telegram are little-endian encoded. Recheck what you are doing. Changing the layer has no effect on this.